# Dynamically localize MainMenu.xib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, internationalization

I need a way to change the strings in the menu bar (MainMenu.xib) in Cocoa application to render dynamically based on the locale I set. I have created MainMenu.strings file for different locales. Currently, all strings that are displayed are for the system locale. Is there a way where I can override this logic to display the strings for the locale I want. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What stops you from running a search?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the standard localization mechanics of OS X/Cocoa?
https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the system locale is not something that OS X applications normally do. Unless you've got a really good reason to do so, it'd be better to just use the user's preferred locale, as set in System Preferences.

If you really want to do this, you can set the "AppleLanguages" user default to whatever locale you want before calling NSApplicationMain, and the application will use that locale.

Like this:

```
// Note: Don't do this.
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@[@"de"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Like he said - possible but nothing apps on OS X usually do. Rethink your use case.

Comment: I need to do this in my app. Setting AppleLanguages worked only for string literals but not for MainMenu.xib.

Comment: Is your MainMenu.xib marked as localized in multiple languages? Are you using Base Internationalization? If *any* of your localized strings show up in the right language, then your locale is getting set properly, and the problem is with the settings on the MainMenu.xib.